# Understanding "possible loss of precision required char found byte"

Tags: java

```
class A  {   
    public static void main(String [] varun) {
        byte b = 65;
        char ch = b;
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Why its give an error:

> possible loss of precision
>     required char
>     found byte

Comment: Is that an error or a warning?

Comment: Please see [Java - Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: More mind-freak, try making `b` `final` and removing the cast.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis try not to be so melodramatic. It is not mind-freak. Putting final on the byte will inline it, so character is safe to assume that the byte won't go below 0. Not convinced? Put -65 for the byte. You will get a compiler error :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error text is misleading.

A `char` is a 2 byte **unsigned** type (range 0 to 65535)

A `byte` is a 1 byte **signed** type (range -128 to 127).

Therefore a `byte` cannot be represented in a `char` in full generality (as you'll lose the negatives). So you get an error; albeit a misleading one.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Short, concise, no casts, just facts.

Answer (score 3):

Byte is 1 byte long, while char is 2 bytes long, so they are incompatible. You need to use casting:

```
class A 
{   
    public static void main(String [] varun)    
    {
        byte b = 65;
        char ch = (char) b;
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put something smaller in something larger. The truth is that char is signed. Try it: int i = 5; long l = i; . And long is 2x bigger. Your argument is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add as explicit cast as byte just take one byte and char is of two byte in java and implicit type cast does not work with byte and char.

Use

> char ch = (char) b;

Comment: This is a workaround, not an explanation. The question is why, not how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
char ch = (char) b;
```

The error it gave you it became from the fact that a byte type is an 8-bit integers and chars is 1-bit plus the bits of encoding (UTF-8, ASCII, etc).
The difference between a byte stream and a character stream is that the character stream attempts to work with characters rather than bytes.
So a byte stream is 8-bit stream without encoding. That's why you have this error.

Answer (score 0):

If You are assigned two different type of primitives to each other You may have two types of casting:

- if You assign `int` to `long`, thus putting smaller type into bigger You perform widening and so called widening conversion - it is also called implicit cast

  int a = 100;
  long b = a;
- on the other hand if You would perform conversion from `long` to `int` You are narrowing the type. Thus You need to perform explicit cast if You don't do that You get that `possible loss of precision`

  long a = 100L;
  int b = (int)a;

or as in Your case as @Bathsheba said "Therefore a byte cannot be represented in a char in full generality (as you'll lose the negatives). So you get an error; albeit a misleading one." - You need to explicitly cast so that You are aware of loosing data.

Answer (score 0):

When one type of data is assigned to another type of variable, an automatic type conversion
will take place if the following two conditions are met:
• The two types are compatible.
• The destination type is larger than the source type.

When these two conditions are met, a widening conversion takes place.

So the reason for it is,

For widening conversions, the numeric types, including integer and floating-point types,
are compatible with each other. However, there are no automatic conversions from the
numeric types to char or boolean.

Comment: A `char` is defined by the JLS as an integral type: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from a `byte` to a `char` is a so-called [Widening and Narrowing Primitive Conversion (JLS 5.1.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4)

> First, the `byte` is converted to an `int` via widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), and then the resulting `int` is converted to a `char` by narrowing primitive conversion ([§5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

The widening conversion from `byte` to `int` is fine (both are signed), but from `int` to `char` will loose both sign and (potentially) range (as `char` is 0 to 65536):

> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and range.

And

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

Because of this potential loss of precision, sign and informaiton you get a compilation error and an explicit cast is necessary to signal to the compiler that you know what you're doing.